# Removing attic house fan and adding subfloor

Tags: repair, attic, subfloor, fans, removal

I'm going to help a friend remove his whole house fan in the attic. Since the attic space is walkable, we need to patch the subfloor where the fan was. There is currently 2x6 joists exposed that can be seen from the 3'x3' hole where the fan is installed.

I was thinking about putting some 2x6 framing together with a framing nailer and using lag  screws to tie into the existing joists on all sides. Is this the right way to go or should I be using joist hangers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very useful if you could post a picture of what the existing framing looks like around the fan opening.

Since it is unlikely that the joists are three feet apart there is a good chance that there are already framing headers across between two existing joists that take care of supporting the stub joist that was cut off across the fan opening. If this is the case then just one piece of 2x6 and a pair of joist hangers would be the simplest thing to add needed ceiling support back across the fan opening.

On the other hand if the opening is different then this is where a picture comes in valuable as to offering you the best advice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have access to take a picture right now but I think you are probably right about existing framing headers. I'll examine it closer to see.